# Divide Subject, From, and To values from headers

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I'm fetching the messages from authorized email but the problem is the separation of Subject, From, and To values from headers in java, I succeed in that below code is working fine but it is taking more time for separation, I have gone through so much Gmail API documentation but I didn't get the solution.

```
ListMessagesResponse listResponse = service.users().messages().list(user).setMaxResults(10L)
                .setLabelIds(labelidlist).setQ(query).execute();

List<Message> listofmesssages = listResponse.getMessages();

HashMap<String, Object> msgsMap;
List messageslist = new ArrayList();

for (Message message : listofmesssages) {
    Message fullmessage = service.users().messages().get("me", message.getId()).setFormat("full").execute();

    msgsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    /*Adding threadid for threadid is required when delete operation has happen*/
    msgsMap.put("threadid", message.getThreadId());
    List<MessagePartHeader> headers = fullmessage.getPayload().getHeaders();

    if (!headers.isEmpty()) {
        for (MessagePartHeader header : headers) {
            String name = header.getName();
            msgsMap.put("msgid", message.getId());

            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Subject")) {
                subject = header.getValue();
                msgsMap.put("subject", subject);
            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("From")) {
                from = header.getValue().split("<")[0];
                msgsMap.put("from", from);
            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("To")) {
                to = header.getValue().split(" ")[0];
                msgsMap.put("to", to);
            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {
                String date = header.getValue();
                java.util.Date fecha = new java.util.Date(date);
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);
                Date date1;
                date1 = (Date) formatter.parse(fecha.toString());
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(date1);
                String formatedDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/"
                                + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                msgsMap.put("date", formatedDate);
            }
        }
    }

    messageslist.add(msgsMap);
}

return messageslist;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue here. What do you mean by `separation`?

Comment: I mean, i want to fetch SUBJECT, FROM, and TO details from headers instead of iterating this many times, is there any possibility to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [message resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages) JSON, you can see that `headers` is an array of objects that contain properties `name` and `value`. There is no property key called `To`, or `Subject`. That's the reason the library you're using has no methods called `getTo`, or `getSubject`.

This makes sense, since headers might not always be the same ones.

Because of this, you cannot specifically fetch a certain header name.

#### Reference:

- [Users.messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages)
- [getHeaders()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/model/MessagePart.html#getHeaders--)